# Weed out combinations with certain condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbee in python and programing, I am trying to come up with combinations and weed out combinations with certain conditions.

So in the case below, I have tried to generate all possible combinations between `1-100`. But I don't know where to go after this.

```
import itertools

i_list = []

for i in range (1, 101):
    i_list.append(i)

comb = itertools.combinations(i_list,2)
for combinations in list(comb):
    print (combinations)
```

This runs fine and will generate a list from `1-100`, and give me an output of

```
(1,2) (1,3).........(98,99) (98,100) (99,100)
```

Now my goal is to weed out the combinations with a difference `< 5`, so for example: `(1,2)` the difference is less than `5`, so it should not be outputted. `(1,8)` the difference is greater than `5`, so it should be outputted. I hope that make sense.

Can anyone guide me through the thought process and suggest an easy approach?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to properly format your code. (Select it, then hit Control+K or use the `{}` button.)

Comment: `i_list = list(range(1,101))`  beside that you do not even need to generate the list - feed `range(1,101)` directly to combinations.

Comment: Ok that make sense. I thought I would have to generate a list so I have something to feed into the combination iterator. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.filterfalse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse) for this and then iterate over the result.

Also, with iterators, you want to wait until you really need a list before you convert to a list with `list()`. There's no reason to ever do that in this case because you are always iterating. This allows you to work with very large sets without taking up the memory and time of running through the iterator just to make a list to then iterate the list:

```
from itertools import combinations, filterfalse

comb = combinations(range(1, 101),2)
filtered = filterfalse(lambda x: abs(x[0] - x[1]) < 5, comb)

for combinations in filtered:
    print (combinations)
```

The iterators produced by `range()`, `combinations` and `fitleredfalse` are all lazy, so they never start evaluating until you start looping over them. This allows you to defer any work until it needs to be done or to iterate over part of a large set without calculating the entire thing.

Comment: Is there any difference between using `itertools.filterfalse()` and `filter()`?
Apart from that filter returns items satisfying a predicate and filterfalse the ones that don't satisfy it?

Comment: Not much @asikorski -- they both produce iterators. I liked `filterfalse` here because the condition was about "weeding things out" rather than including things. Just thought it was easier to reason about.

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to restrict the generated values to be kept inside the list:

```
from itertools import combinations

comb = [ x for x in combinations(range(1,101),2) if x[1]-x[0]>4 ]

print (comb)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), ... snipp ..., (93, 99), (93, 100), (94, 99), (94, 100), (95, 100)]
```

`combinations` respects the order of numbers so no `abs()` around `x[1]-x[0]` needed - range itself is a sequence and your resulting list weeds out all numbers you do not want due to the `if x[1]-x[0]>4` condition.

Answer (score 1):

This should accomplish what you are asking:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> combinations = itertools.combinations(range(1, 101), 2)
>>> generator = ((a, b) for a, b in combinations if b - a >= 5)
>>> for pair in generator:
    print(pair, end=' ')


(1, 6) (1, 7) (1, 8) (1, 9) (1, 10) (1, 11) (1, 12) (1, 13) (1, 14) (1, 15) ...
```

Alternatively, you can try this instead to do the exact same thing:

```
>>> generator = ((a, b) for a in range(1, 96) for b in range(a + 5, 101))
>>> for pair in generator:
    print(pair, end=' ')


(1, 6) (1, 7) (1, 8) (1, 9) (1, 10) (1, 11) (1, 12) (1, 13) (1, 14) (1, 15) ...
```

Comment: Neat way to produce only what you need in the first place